# Angular FormGroup array

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-reactive-forms, formarray, formgroups

I have a problem with the set the data to the form array. Scenario is when filling user details, some users have multiple addresses.

here is User.ts

```
export interface User {
  id?: number;
  name: string;
  age: number;
  address: MyAddress;
}
```

MyAddress.ts

```
export interface MyAddress {
  id?: number;
  line1: string;
  line2: string;
  postalCode: string;
  city: string;
}
```

In component.ts file

```
myForm = this.formBuilder.group({
    name: ['', Validators.required],
    age: ['', Validators.required]
});

myFormAddress = this.formBuilder.group({
    address: this.formBuilder.array([]),
});

setDetail(): User {
    let myObj = new User();
    myObj.name = this.myForm.controls.name.getRawValue();
    myObj.age = this.myForm.controls.description.getRawValue();
    
    myObj.address = {
      //need to set form array dta here
    }
    
    return myObj;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your User interface should reflect the possibility of having multiple addresses:

```
export interface User {
  id?: number;
  name: string;
  age: number;
  address: MyAddress[];
}
```

and address should be a part of myForm:

```
myForm = this.formBuilder.group({
  name: ['', Validators.required],
  age: ['', Validators.required],
  address: this.formBuilder.array([]),
});
```

Then you should be able to get the array like you do with a regular form control:

```
myObj.address = this.myForm.controls.address.getRawValue();
```

Another option is to just get the whole object from the form value:

```
myObj = this.myForm.value as User;
```

Comment: address is an array. I need to return address as single value of combining line1, line2, postalcode, country.

Comment: Ex: line1 = 'No.45'   line2 = 'xyz lane'   postalcode = 1234   country= UK,   in db it should save under address= 'No.45  xyz lane 1234  UK'.    
  is this possible? ``` myObj.address = [ { } ] ```

Comment: From the code, you provided in the question I can see that MyAddress is an object with few fields. My understanding now is that you want to concat these fields into a single string value. From the User interface, I see the address field is not an array or even a string but a type of MyAddress. So address filed on the User object can only contain an object of type MyAddress. This is from your definition. You said that users can have multiple addresses. Your interfaces don't reflect it. I'm a bit lost. Answering the question "Is it possible to concat MyAddress fields into a single string" - yes.

Answer (score 0):

You needn't two formGroups:

```
myForm = this.formBuilder.group({
    name: ['', Validators.required],
    age: ['', Validators.required],
    address: this.formBuilder.array([]),
});
```