# Set Formarray data to an object angular

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-reactive-forms, formarray, formgroups

I'm a beginner to the angular. need to save multiple addresses to a user. I need to assign address values to an object. 
these are interfaces

```
export interface User {
 name: string;
 myAddress: MyAddress[]
}

export interface MyAddress {
  id?: number;
  line1: string;
  line2: string;
  postalCode: string;
  city: string;
}
```

component.ts file

```
myForm = this.formBuilder.group({
   name: ['', Validators.required],
   address: this.formBuilder.array([]),
});

get myAddresses() {
  return this.formAddress.controls['address'] as FormArray;
}

addAddressFormGroup() {
    const addressData = this.formBuilder.group({
      line1: ['', Validators.required],
      line2: [''],
      postalCode: ['', Validators.required],
      city: ['', Validators.required],
    });
    this.myAddresses.push(addressData);
 }
```

data are set to the obj.

```
setDetail(): User {
    let myObj = new User();
    myObj.name = this.myForm.controls.name.getRawValue();//this is how i set other values

    myObj.address = {
      // i need to call address arraydata (line1,line2,city,postalcode) here
    }
    
    return myObj;
  }
```

need to return data as `myobj`. I can't understand how to do this. is this possible to do?

Comment: it's the same question that your [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75296334/angular-formgroup-array)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. `User` is an interface, you can't create `User` instance with empty constructor unless you declare `User` as class.
2. To get the address' value, use `this.myAddresses.getRawValue()` and cast it as `MyAddress[]`.

Your code should be as below:

```
let myObj: User = {
  name: this.myForm.controls.name.getRawValue(),
  myAddress: this.myAddresses.getRawValue() as MyAddress[],
};
```

[Demo @ StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-buqmpm?file=src/main.ts)